# Ionic content shows up only after clicking on SideMenu

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, aws-api-gateway

I have an ionic App which was working fine but now It is showing little weird behaviour, When I run the app it does not show the data at first but when I click on side menu once or twice then it loads and shows the data. I have an nodejs api from which the data comes to my app and the same api has been put in aws api gateway, I noticed this behaviour since I implemented aws sdk for binding data in my APP.

What can be the root cause for the same?
I can share the code but I am not sure where the issue is whether in controllers or views?

Comment: may be because getting response from api take a while...And you are getting repsonse in time when you open menu. i am just saying case.
have you added loding in api call?

Comment: No I can see the response coming in time however content is not showing, I tried waiting for some time just to see if it shows the data later but It only shows when click on side menu, else it has no content. I also see a warning **Deferred long-running timer task(s) to improve scrolling smoothness. See crbug.com/574343** in console.

Comment: okey may be some event fire on menu click. check that

Comment: Does anyone have answer on this?

Comment: it is impossible to say anything about it without debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using Ionic Loader as the reponse was taking long time. My side menu was not getting initialized with the same time as other views hence views were not rendering without sidemenu being rendered, The idea is to show a loader on every response and hide it when it's a success, so it will render the views successfully.
Hope it helps.